# Any way to keep track of current running app from background?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, background

I would like to create an application which, while in the background, keeps track of the current app which is loaded and being used.

Is there any way to have my app, periodically check which app is currently being run? My thought is to keep track of the time when an app is loaded and then when it is closed and find the difference in time but I'm unsure if I can give my app access to this data.

Thanks

Comment: Lots of good answers here, but the key to realize is that this *directly* runs counter to Apple's intent for background processes. So even if you find a very clever way to pull it off, it is likely that Apple will close that loophole in the future. This would be considered spying on the user, which is a major thing Apple is trying to prevent. It would be helpful to explain what problem you're trying to solve. There may be another answer if it's something users would actively want.

Comment: I have some Java experience but I'm just getting into coding with Swift. I thought a nice first project that could help people would be a productivity app which keeps track of the amount of time that they spend on social media applications. I know this would help keep me focused as I waste hours a day on social media and tracking it would help me to reduce my wasted time. Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: This is possible on Mac (I actually built it; it's a bit harder than it sounds for various OS-level reasons). It is not possible (by design) on iOS. A creative idea, but you'll need another one.

Answer (score 2):

You can´t execute code in the background in you iOS device. There are a few exceptions but what you´re trying to do is not included in that.

Answer (score 1):

This *might* be possible - there's an app called Moment which tracks your screen time while in the background. It does so by using always-on GPS, one of (if not the only) thing that can run in the background. Maybe that's a place to start looking.

Comment: I just downloaded Moment and it is almost exactly what I wanted to do. Oh well, I still might try to build the app for learning purposes. Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: That's very interesting, and thanks for the pointer. I would expect Moment to get shut down by Apple eventually. (Once upon a time I would have been shocked that it got through app review at all, but I've grown a bit cynical about that…)

Answer (score 1):

An app can execute code in the background, but Apple will reject App store submissions that do so, except for a few allowed purposes.  For private developer and Ad Hoc apps, maybe OK though.

However, Apple currently hides all information about other app processes from your app's sandbox for privacy and security reasons.  They will be invisible to your background code.  So, no way, on stock OS iOS devices.